# Area between contours of two surfaces

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, regions

If I have the two following surfaces:

```
f[x_, y_] := y^3 - x^3 + 3 x^2 - 6 x - 4 y + 4
g[x_, y_] := x^3 + y^3 + x - 2 y - 1
```

And the two lines defined by the contours:

```
f[x,y] == 0
g[x,y] == 0
```

Then how can I get the region between the two contours?

I have the points of intersection which are the results in the first quadrant given by:

```
solution = {x, y} /. NSolve[ f[x, y] == g[x, y] == 0, Reals]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an approach that involves some manual inspection, but works nonetheless.

First let's look at the two curves:

```
f[x_, y_] := y^3 - x^3 + 3 x^2 - 6 x - 4 y + 4
g[x_, y_] := x^3 + y^3 + x - 2 y - 1

ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

We see there's 2 components we're interested in. To find them, let's look to see where `f` and `g` are negative:

```
RegionPlot[{f[x, y] < 0, g[x, y] < 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

So by inspection, we can see the region of interest is

> ```
> f[x, y] < 0 && g[x, y] < 0 && y > 0 (* top component *)
> f[x, y] > 0 && g[x, y] > 0 && y < 1 (* bottom component *)
> ```

Visualize:

```
cond = (f[x, y] < 0 && g[x, y] < 0 && y > 0) || (f[x, y] > 0 && g[x, y] > 0 && y < 1);

RegionPlot[cond, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

We can ask for the area using an `ImplicitRegion` representation. Unfortunately (with `Area`) the exact form cannot be found, but we can get an approximate answer:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[cond, {x, y}];

Area[reg, Method -> "NIntegrate"]
```

> ```
> 3.01605
> ```

```
Area[reg, Method -> {"NIntegrate", WorkingPrecision -> 20}]
```

> ```
> 3.0160539632460586365
> ```

Comment: That's just what I was looking for! I should have said that I was only taking the top region, so I  just used `NSolve` to find the y value to split the condition, and got the top integral to 0.79...

Comment: Right. To use those endpoints you found with `NSolve`, then you'd need to do `Integrate[1, {y, pt1, pt2}, {x, f1[y], f2[y]}]`, where `f1` and `f2` are messy inverses of `f` and `g`, respectively.

Answer (score 10):

The area between two curves can be computed symbolically in a manner which makes it clear what is the basic idea behind the problem.

From the `ContourPlot` one can see that we could calculate `x` as a function of `y` for the both curves, we have:

```
Solve[y^3 - x^3 + 3 x^2 - 6 x - 4 y + 4 == 0, {y, x}, Reals] // Quiet
Solve[x^3 + y^3 + x - 2 y - 1 == 0, {y, x}, Reals] // Quiet
```

> ```
> {{x -> Root[-4 + 4 y - y^3 + 6 #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]}}
>   {{x -> Root[-1 - 2 y + y^3 + #1 + #1^3 &, 1]}}
> ```

Next we find the intersection points:

```
{r1, r2, r3} = y /. Solve[ Root[-4 + 4 y - y^3 + 6 #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]
                           == Root[-1 - 2 y + y^3 + #1 + #1^3 &, 1], y]
```

> ```
> { Root[67 - 382 #1 - 324 #1^2 - 95 #1^3 + 270 #1^4 + 216 #1^5 - 
>           51 #1^6 - 72 #1^7 + 8 #1^9 &, 1], 
>    Root[67 - 382 #1 - 324 #1^2 - 95 #1^3 + 270 #1^4 + 216 #1^5 - 
>         51 #1^6 - 72 #1^7 + 8 #1^9 &, 2], 
>    Root[67 - 382 #1 - 324 #1^2 - 95 #1^3 + 270 #1^4 + 216 #1^5 - 
>         51 #1^6 - 72 #1^7 + 8 #1^9 &, 3]}
> ```

And here we have a symbolic solution:

```
Integrate[
  Abs[Root[-4 + 4 y - y^3 + 6 #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1] - 
      Root[-1 - 2 y + y^3 + #1 + #1^3 &, 1]],
  {y, Root[67 - 382 #1 - 324 #1^2 - 95 #1^3 + 270 #1^4 + 216 #1^5 - 
           51 #1^6 - 72 #1^7 + 8 #1^9 &, 1], 
      Root[67 - 382 #1 - 324 #1^2 - 95 #1^3 + 270 #1^4 + 216 #1^5 - 
           51 #1^6 - 72 #1^7 + 8 #1^9 &, 3]}]
```

Since there we have roots of nineth order polynomial and the third order polynomila roots are quite involved the system cannot integrate the expression exactly. Nontheless we can find a good estimate:

```
NIntegrate[ Abs[Root[-4 + 4 y - y^3 + 6 #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1] - 
                Root[-1 - 2 y + y^3 + #1 + #1^3 &, 1]], {y, r1, r3}]
```

> ```
>  3.01605
> ```

```
Rotate [Plot[{ConditionalExpression[-Root[-4 + 4 y - y^3 + 6 #1 - 
    3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], r1 <= y <= r3], 
             ConditionalExpression[-Root[-1 - 2 y + y^3 + #1 + #1^3 &, 1], 
                                    r1 <= y <= r3]},
          {y, -1.85, 1.55}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
          PlotRange -> {-1.85, 1.55}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
          Filling -> {1 -> {2}}], 90 Degree]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I propose another solution based on extracting the point of the mesh generated by the two contours. First, I generate the plots with the mesh curve $f=g=0$:

```
pl1 = Plot3D[#, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 MeshStyle -> {White, Thickness[0.007]}, ImageSize -> 500, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Directive[Opacity[0.4]]}, 
 SphericalRegion -> True, AxesLabel -> Automatic] & /@ {f, g};
```

Now I extract the point of the both meshes and create a curve by interpolation:

```
ptsf = Join @@ Cases[Normal@#, Line[x1__] :> x1, Infinity] & /@ pl1;
flip1 = Interpolation[{#[[2]], #[[1]]} & /@ ptsf[[1]], 
Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 3];
flip2 = Interpolation[{#[[2]], #[[1]]} & /@ ptsf[[2]], 
Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 3];
```

The the region between the two curves (taking into account the intersection points):

```
Plot[{flip1[x], flip2[x]}, {x, solution[[1, 2]], solution[[3, 2]]}, 
Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> True, 
RotateLabel -> False, 
FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 24, Italic,FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"] & /@ {"y", "x"}), 
PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, All}]
```

[image]

It is easy obtain the area of the region for comparison to previous answers:

```
NIntegrate[Abs[flip1[x] - flip2[x]], {x, solution[[1, 2]], solution[[2, 2]], 
solution[[3, 2]]}, Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"]
```

yielding `3.01553`. We can see that there is some difference in this value. I have checked that depends on the plot sampling, so coarse sampling gives lower value than those previous reported.